# Fantasy Movie: Barbarian-esque w/ Cannibalism (maybe)

Tags: story-identification

So I was around 7-9 when I saw the first 10 minutes or so of this movie. It was on VHS, around the time VHS had become mainstream so maybe ('83-'85.) I've tried to find this movie many times since I saw the beginning and forced my parents to turn it off, to no avail.

The movie opens with a "barbarian" male and female navigating a rocky, barren, terrain kinda like in the beginning scenes of 'The Warrior and the Sorceress.'

As a child, I interpreted the male character as the main protagonist, but as you will see that was definitely not the case.

The pair get cornered by some Morlock looking dudes (like a whole group of them.) The male tries to fight, but is pretty quickly subdued and his head is bashed in (or something equally brutal and indicating he is *not* the protagonist.) The entire time the female counterpart is freaking out. My memory gets super fuzzy here, but I believe there is a scene (green inferno style) where the female is captured and watching the "morlocks" cook/eat her male companion. It is right around there that I was successful in petitioning my parents to turn the movie off.

Movies it is not:

- Conan
- Beastmaster
- Krull
- Barbarian Queen
- Red Sonja
- The Warrior and the Sorceress
- Deathstalker (looked promising with the initial sequence, but alas isn't it.)

Comment: Any of [these on IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/list/ls066162946/) seem familiar?

Comment: @bob1 no - those all look like cannibal horror movies. The movie I described was fantasy first. I'm not even sure if the rest of the movie had horror elements in it, as I only saw the opening scene.

Comment: Does this ring a bell? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Boy_and_His_Dog_(1975_film)

Comment: @jo1storm doesn't look familiar. Watched the first 5 minutes and none of that sparked anything.

Comment: I know this is a really old thread... But if you are still looking try going through the list of sword and sorcery films on Wikipedia... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sword_and_sorcery_films Maybe it is listed there? ... I was looking for a similar movie involving a similar scene (cannibalism but a king/leader eating a human heart taken from a man on an alter) but it wasn't at the beginning, it was farther in. It ended up being The Blade Master/ Ator 2 .... I don't think that is the movie you are looking for. But maybe it is on the list too.

Comment: Are you sure it was a fantasy barbarian movie and not a caveman movie?  What fantasy elements do you remember?

Comment: @ParkerMacInnis I am not sure, and honestly didn't consider it expanding the vocabulary of my description to widen the net. Do any caveman movies come to mind that might fit the bill?

Comment: @AWilson I'll take a look at your list!